# How to get the list of running applications on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

I have a task where I need to get the list of running applications(not running processes) on a remote machine. So far I have tried this on Powershell :
$result=gps | ? {$_.mainwindowtitle.length -ne 0}
I tried running the above commands remotely but I have now found out that mainwindowtitle is not supported for remote execution(MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx)
It will be great if you can suggest me other ways through which I can retrieve the list of running applications (not running processes) from the remote machine.

Comment: Can you use powershell remoting or it's not an option?

Comment: I can use powershell remoting but the above command is still not working.

Comment: Yes it's true: there is a `NotSupportedException` when you are trying to access the `MainWindowTitle` property for a process that is running on a remote computer. #This property is available only for processes that are running on the local computer.#

Comment: Hi so is there any other way to get the list of applications running on the remote computer?? :(

Comment: A quick test with `Invoke-Command` and `Process.MainWindowTitle` is not populated (but it is locally). Suspect this might be a case of the Window Titles not being available from a different session.

Comment: Yes Richard I also tried that with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the WASP addin module:

http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Should be able to get you the info you want.

Comment: I think you did not get what I was asking? getting processes can be done but I am stuck with getting the list of running applications (not processes).

Comment: I am not sure you can do that, you can pick out an exe but a process could also be an exe. Do you know specific apps you are looking to see if they are running or you purely want to know the the exe's running that are actual applications (user interactable programs) that are open.

Comment: I actually want to get the applications as shown in application tab in the task manager of the remote machine.

Comment: WASP should be able to help you with that.